# Manhattan distance for a 2d toroid

Tags: javascript, c, math, distance

for the last 1.5 hours I've been struggling to write a function to calculate [manhattan distance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) for a square [toroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroid) (like playing the classic snake game without walls).

What I have (coding it in JavaScript)

```
function getManhattanDistance( node1, node2, size )
{
    size = parseInt( size / 2 );
    var dist1 = Math.abs( node1.x - node2.x );
    var dist2 = Math.abs( node1.y - node2.y );

    if ( dist1 < size && dist2 < size )
    {
        return dist1 + dist2;
    }

    if ( dist1 >= size )
    {
        var x1 = Math.min( node1.x, node2.x );
        var x2 = Math.max( node1.x, node2.x );
        x1 += size;
        if ( dist2 < size )
        {
            return Math.abs( x1 - x2 ) + dist2;
        }
        var y1 = Math.min( node1.y, node2.y );
        var y2 = Math.max( node1.y, node2.y );
        y1 += size;
        return Math.abs( x1 - x2 ) + Math.abs( y1 - y2 );
    }

    var y1 = Math.min( node1.y, node2.y );
    var y2 = Math.max( node1.y, node2.y );
    y1 += size;
    return dist1 + Math.abs( y1 - y2 );

}
```

I wrote some tests on what this does on a 5*5 toroid:

Manhattance distance 0,1; 2,2 is 1 should be 3
Manhattance distance 2,2; 0,1 is 1 should be 3
Manhattance distance 2,1; 3,4 is 2 should be 2
Manhattance distance 3,4; 2,1 is 2 should be 2
Manhattance distance 2,1; 4,4 is 1 should be 5
Manhattance distance 4,4; 2,1 is 1 should be 5

Thank you, guys!

Comment: Ofc. it is not, but for a lot of AI simulators this is a valuable thing that can save time and is still missing in the SO database. But thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @IgorLacik: Shouldn't the distance from (2,1) to (3,4) be 3? And the distance from (2,1) to (4,4) should be 4?

Comment: @Martin R: 2,1 to 3,4 should be 2, but yes, 2,1 to 4,4 should be 4. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorLacik: (2,1)->(2,0)->(2,4)->(3,4) makes a distance of 3. Or did I misunderstand the problem?

Comment: No, you are right. Was looking at the wrong node.

Comment: Thank you guys ( Oli for trying to get the SO site better and Martin for actually helping :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can "walk" in x-direction either directly from x1 to x2 (`abs(x1 - x2)` steps), or wrap around in increasing x-direction (`size + x2 - x1` steps) or in decreasing x-direction (`x1 - x2 + size` steps).

Therefore the difference in x-direction is

```
 dx = min ( abs(x1 - x2) , size + x2 - x1, x1 - x2 + size)
```

and similarly

```
 dy = min ( abs(y1 - y2) , size + y2 - y1, y1 - y2 + size)
```

and finally the Manhattan distance

```
 dist = dx + dy
```

*Update:* Another way to look at it is that the distance in x-direction is
either `abs(x2-x1)` if you don't wrap around, or `size - abs(x2-x1)` if you wrap around.
Therefore

```
 dx = min ( abs(x2 - x1) , size - abs(x2 - x1) )
```

which is a more symmetric way of expressing it.

*Update*: Final JavaScript Function:

```
function getToroidManhattanDistance( node1, node2, size )
{
    var dx = Math.min( Math.abs( node1.x - node2.x ), size - Math.abs( node2.x - node1.x ) );
    var dy = Math.min( Math.abs( node1.y - node2.y ), size - Math.abs( node2.y - node1.y ) );
    return dx + dy;    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. finally understood it